# What could the purpose of replacing %20 with spaces before doing PHP rawurlencode() be?

Tags: php, urlencode

It's a pretty silly question, sorry. There is a big and rather complex system that has a bug and I managed to track it down to this piece

```
return str_replace('%2F', '/', rawurlencode(str_replace('%20', ' ', $key)));
```

There is a comment explaining why slashes are replaced - to preserve path structure, e.g. encoded1/encoded2/etc. However there is no explanation whatsoever why %20 is replaced with space and that part is the direct cause of a bug. I am tempted to just remove str_replace() but it looks like it was placed there for some reason and I have a feeling that I'll break something else by doing this. Has anyone encountered anything similar? Perhaps it's a dirty fix for some PHP bug? Any guesses and insights are highly appreciated!

Comment: +1 because I've been down this same rabbit hole, and it's not fun. Its a long shot, but is there an SVN repository for this project? Maybe the commit history might give you some clues as to why this is here?

Comment: Yeah I did examine all history of commits and sadly this line has been created like that and was never changed. Also it has been added a few months ago only so it might be relatively safe to assume that this is in a fact a mistake. The only thing preventing me from doing this assumption right away is that the system was created by huge corporation that generally does things pretty professionally (well, at least I've got such impression so far).

Comment: No company, no matter how big, has got perfect code. Doing things professionally does not mean the code is well written. In fact, in my experience it often means quite the opposite. The veneer of professionalism hides an underlying code rot. But if this change was only made a few months ago, can you not ask the person who made it what's going on?

Comment: Can you post an sample values that are passed to that function?

Comment: Sample values would be dir1/dir2/file.txt. The system in question is Amazon's PHP SDK. I am not sure how easy it would be for me to contact the author since I am not directly related to that company. Anyway I've committed the fix and we'll see what they say :) Thanks everyone for the help! https://github.com/eugenebond/aws-sdk-php/commit/532712e23b3e55c0d8666326767a5b412824ac2c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing so would prevent `%20` (encoded space) from being encoded to `%2F20`. However, it only serves to prevent double escaped spaces; other special characters would still get double encoded.

This is a sign of bad code; strings that are passed into this function shouldn't be allowed to have encoded characters in the first place.

I would recommend creating unit tests that cover all referencing code and then refactor this function to remove the `str_replace()` to make sure it doesn't break the tests.

Answer (score 1):

First thing that jumps to mind is as a mitigation technique against double encoding.

Not that I would recommend doing such a thing this way, as it would get real messy real quickly (and one would already wonder why only that entity, perhaps 'they' never experienced issues with any others... yet).

Comment: it certainly looks like there's some double-encoding going on (especially with the `%2F` being replaced back to a slash... ouch, nasty, nasty code)

Answer (score 1):

It could be the result of a misunderstanding of `rawurlencode()` vs `urlencode()`

`urlencode()` replaces spaces with `+` signs

If the original author thought that `rawurlencode()` did the same thing, they would be attempting to pre-encode the spaces so they don't get turned into `+`s

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that too. However they don't seem to be doing that, they actually decode %20 back into spaces before passing it to rawurlencode()